# Xampp -mysql in xampp starts and stops after a while

Tags: mysql

when I click to start MySQL it start but after a while it suddenly stop. Here is the response that show in Xampp control panel.

Status change detected: running
Status change detected: stopped

Comment: 1) unfortunately, there is no way anyone can tell you what has gone wrong since you have not shared any information apart from the fact that you mysql stopped. 2) this question has nothing to do with programming, so it is off topic here on SO. You may get help at superuser or dba sister sites. But even there you need to share more in order to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these steps below :

1-windows + R (opens run window)

2-type in services.msc

3-check if the service mysql is set as disabled. (change it to automatic)

or

1-quit the XAMPP

2-cut the All files in C:\xampp\mysql\backup

3-paste and replace files in C:\xampp\mysql\data

4-run as administrator the XAMPP